# Monitor the nginx deployed on GKE cluster

Tags: nginx, monitoring, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, performance-monitoring

I want to monitor the nginx requests (5xx, 4xx, 3xx, 2xx) where multiple applications are running with different domain urls.

Nginx is deployed as Kind : Deployment. Is there a way for real time monitoring ?

Comment: Are you using prometheus or any other monitoring tool in your GKE cluster?

Comment: https://en.lmgtfy.app/#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=nginx%20real%20time%20monitoring

This really depends... so please search for options and think wat you really need. Do you need real-time stats or do you need just historic information (that you could extract from access-logs)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use Grafana as well but you need to enable metrics in the nginx server.

1. Enable prometheus scrapper annotation in nginx service file. Assuming nginx is already exposing metrics to the /metrics endpoint.
2. Fetch metrics using Prometheus
3. Build custom Grafana dashboards.